# Holoviews: how can a subfigure layout be saved as multiple files?

Tags: python-3.x, holoviews

Typesetting programs like LaTeX often require separate image files for each element of a subplot layout. 
Is it possible to save each individual component of a Holoviews layout as a separate file? As it is, the matplotlib backend outputs a single SVG with all three elements of the layout side by side.
The issue with the brute force solution where each plot is simply plotted separately is that the plots are not normalized with respect to each other like they would be as part of a layout.

Answer (score 0):

With matplotlib backend, if you would like to revert back to the base matplotlib figure, you could call `hv.renderer('matplotlib').get_plot(your_layout_variable).state` and it should give you back your matplotlib figure and you can call fig.get_children() to loop through and save.

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('matplotlib')

fig = hv.renderer('matplotlib').get_plot(hv.Curve((np.arange(0, 10))) + hv.Curve((np.arange(0, 10)))).state
fig.get_children()
```

[image]

---

If you're using bokeh backend, when you press the Save icon in the toolbar on any layout, it saves each element in the layout separately as a png file.

If you would like SVGs separately, using the bokeh backend, I created a tool to save SVGs individually https://holoext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/save_to_png_svg.html